# Setting feature label in HTML5 Viewer of Geocortex Essentials?

Tags: arcgis-online, geocortex

While I can edit layer properties in Geocortex Essentials 4.4 and change its label name and other properties, feature label never appears on my feature layer. Feature layers are loaded in Geocortex Essentials Site from ArcGIS Online account.

Can any one please guide me with some basic understanding. I m newbie to Geocortex Essentials and the Geocortex Viewer for HTML5.

Comment: Whenever I see GE, I assume Google Earth, or General Electric, so I recommend writing out Geocortex Essentials.  What does GVH stand for?

Comment: GVH is "Geocortex Viewer for HTML5"

Answer (score 0):

The feature label setting is not for displaying a label in the map. It is used as a header for the object info in search result lists etc. See "About Feature Descriptions" in the Administrators Guide.

If you want to label your objects in the map, you need to add this to the service you publish.

(this is based on experience with the 4.3 version, but it shouldn't be much different)

Comment: Ok so how do i create labels while publishing my feature layer from arcgis online. I changed symbology for my layers in arcgis online map and that reflected in GE. But labels never appears.

Comment: I have not used AGOL as a publishing tool. Since the labels you add in AGOL are added in the map and not the feature service, I can imagine them not being carried over (as I also have verified by testing now). I'm not sure why layer symbology is carried over and not lables. I'd check with Latitude to see what they think...

Comment: Thanks  a lot Havard for your response. Meanwhile  this query about labels is answered, can u look at other GE query related to identity server - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163404/geocortex-essentials-identity-server-credentials

Comment: Alas, I have little-to-none experience with authentication systems in GA ...

Comment: Oops - I m a total newbie to GE and trying hard to work with workflows and other configurations. Documentations to workflow (external commands , parameters, etc) is not for beginners like me. So its hard time for me overall.

Comment: It says 'add this' - add what?