# Geocortex essentials Identity server credentials?

Tags: arcgis-online, geocortex, user-account

I am working with Gecortex Essentials 4.4 and HTML5 viewer 2.5. Feature layers are getting loaded to the site from ArcGIS Online account (created for my organization). I have set up geocortex identity server with few users and roles (admin and general)  as GE site should work based on user authentication.

But issue is if i log in with GE Identity server credentials, feature layers never load (as arcgis online log-in is never done).

Is there a way to store arcgis online credentials somewhere in config file and call that setting on site startup to load feature layer?

This way i can use both identity server and can also load feature layers from arcgis online account.

Answer (score 2):

An end user can only access secured content from ArcGIS Online if they have signed in to ArcGIS Online.  You need to change your security provider from Identity Server to ArcGIS Online, or make the layer public.

There is no way to give Essentials ArcGIS Online credentials and allow it to grant access to secured ArcGIS Online content for non-AGOL users.

Comment: Thank u MWalker. I came with this question bcoz somewhere in GE Forums i came across this workaround solution (refer below comment) I thought of storing AGOL credentials in config and invoking and retrieving them via workflow at site startup and then using identity server credentials for rest processing. Link - https://support.geocortex.com/SupportForums/Thread.aspx?thread=52497&mid=2&pageid=0&ItemID=20

Comment: Forum Content - Storing credentials on the server and retrieving them in workflow

You can add keyed values to your web.config file and retrieve them in workflow activities such as get token. To setup these key value pairs, you can open up your REST web.config file located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Latitude Geographics\Geocortex Essentials\Default\REST Elements\REST. At the top of this config file will be an <appsettings> node which contains <add> nodes. Here are some sample key values:
    <add key="SecureUser" value="user" />
    <add key="SecurePassword" value="password123" />

Comment: Hi rina, those instructions let you store an arbitrary username and password in the application settings and then retrieve those settings at run-time within a workflow.  There still isn't any way for Essentials to sign a user in to ArcGIS Online, or for it to access secured content.